# why I'm getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError (when calling c function from java)?

Tags: java, swig

I'm trying to call simple c function from java (using swig):

Example.c:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return (x+y);
}
```

Example.h:

```
int add(int x, int y);
```

Example.i:

```
%module Example

%{
#include "Example.h"
%}
int add(int x, int y);
```

I created java files using:
`swig -java -package mainPkg Example.i`

My Java application:

```
package mainPkg;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(Example.add(3, 5));

    }

}
```

But I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mainPkg.ExampleJNI.add(II)I
    at mainPkg.ExampleJNI.add(Native Method)
    at mainPkg.Example.add(Example.java:13)
    at mainPkg.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Why ? And how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
static { System.loadLibrary("Example_C_LIB"); }
```

Solved it with